# Minio, is there a way to automatically delete a File after it was downloaded

Tags: linux, file, automation, minio

I use minio to transfere files between clients that are not neccessary online at the same time, so I upload a file to minio and inform the other client that there is a file for to download.

After the client downloaded the file I have no need for the file on the server anymore.

So now to the question, is there a way to setup the Minio server or bucket to, delete the file after a successfull download.

I am aware that I could make a command on the client that he should signal the server to delete the file, but I thought there might be a way to acomplish that without updatating the many different clients we use.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is for the same client to delete the file, as you've mentioned. But this can make your codebase bloated depending on how many of these you need to do.

That being said MinIO does provide 2 features that you can use to make your codebase simpler.

- [Bucket Notifications](https://min.io/docs/minio/linux/administration/monitoring/bucket-notifications.html): Notifications allow you to send messages to receivers such as RabbitMQ, Kafka, AMPQ, among others which the other client can read and perform action.
- [Transform with Lambda](https://min.io/docs/minio/linux/developers/transforms-with-object-lambda.html): You can write a small function (aka Lambda Handler) to do operations on an existing object and then do various operations it in like modifying the data within the object or removing it altogether.

In all the above methods you need a piece of code somewhere to do the delete operation on the file you don't need anymore. Its just a matter of where you want to implement it.

Comment: I came across the same function my self yesterday and I wrote a small WebHook listener that, deletes the File 10 minutes after it was accessed, that should be plenty of time to finish the download.